# Magento configurable product not showing all posible combinations

Tags: magento, frontend, configurable-product

I am using an attribute set for all the jeans products which have waist size, inseam and color. I managed to add the products to the configurable product but now all the options don't show in the front end. I already add all the options to the attributes and also linked the single products to the configurable product. The first product I created shows the correct attributes but the second one doesnt, instead it shows exactly the same options than the first product even when the extra options were already added as single products.

This is the product in question:http://geveysim.net/ValleyBigandTall/index.php/copper-cove-big-and-tall-stonewashed-denim-jeans.html

This is the product showing correctly: http://geveysim.net/ValleyBigandTall/index.php/casual-wear/jeans/greystone-big-and-tall-570-cargo-jeans.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

01) check the quantity in all simple products and make it as in stock
02) after changed go to configuration and re-index